# Orthogonal parametrization of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let a smooth function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be given. I want to construct a surjective function $\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(\phi(u,v)) = f(\phi(u,v'))$ for all $u,v,v'$, and $\phi_u \cdot \phi_v = 0$ everywhere. Note that the first condition can also be written as $\phi_v \cdot \nabla f = 0$, which in turn implies that $\phi_u$ is parallel to $\nabla f$.

One of my initial thoughts was to solve the differential equations $\phi_u = \nabla f(\phi)$, $\phi_v = \begin{pmatrix} -f_y(\phi) \\ f_x(\phi) \end{pmatrix}$; however, in general this will not work due to the requirement of equality of mixed partials. One though, then, is to replace the second equation by $\phi_v = \lambda\begin{pmatrix} -f_y \\ f_x \end{pmatrix}$ for some carefully chosen function $\lambda$ so as to ensure that the mixed partials are equal. However, actually doing the differentiation gets quite messy and it's not clear how to solve for $\lambda$.

A simple example with the function $f = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ has $\phi(u,v) = (u\cos v,u\sin v)$, and $\lambda = u = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ as a solution.

Does such a function $\phi$ always exist? If so, how can it be constructed, and if not, what conditions must $f$ satisfy in order for $\phi$ to exist?

Comment: Of course it exists, just take $\phi = 0$ (or any other constant in $\mathbb R^2$).

Comment: Forgot to mention that $\phi$ should be surjective, sorry.